# Doctrine2 - OneToMany/ManyToOne Bidirectional not working

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many, fosuserbundle

Hi everyone and thanks for help,

I'm currently dealing with a problem while I want to make an OneToMany/ManyToOne Bidirectional Relationship with Doctrine2 (& Symfony2).

Here are my two classes : User (which extends FOSUser) and collection which represents a collection of videos. 
Of course, a user can have several collections, but a collection is only related to one user.

```
/* COLLECTION */
namespace Com\ComBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * Com\ComBundle\Entity\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="collection")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Collection
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Com\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="collections")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param Com\UserBundle\Entity\User $user
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function setUser(\Com\UserBundle\Entity\User $user) {
        $this->user = $user;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return Com\UserBundle\Entity\User User 
     */
    public function getUser() {
        return $this->user;
    }

}
```

And user,

```
    /* USER */    
namespace Com\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /* 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Com\ComBundle\Entity\Collection", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $collections;


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->collections = \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }       
}
```

When I use the doctrine:generate:entities command, it does not generate the methods relative to $collections (get/add/remove), and even if I wrote it myself, it does not work. 
getCollections() return NULL for example.

What am I missing in this code ?

Comment: You have a typo at inversedBy. It says colelction

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your answer,
I corrected it, but it is not working better. There was a problem there indeed, but it should still remain another one.

Comment: The problem was very simple, in fact. A star was missing and the annotation was ignored 
/*(*) 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Com\ComBundle\Entity\Collection", mappedBy="user")
 */

Comment: Oh wow. That must've bugged you quite.